# Possible to have 2 SSL certificates in Apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, ssl, ssl-certificate

I would like to change the hostname of an Apache 2.2.15-28.el6 (CentOS6) webserver from `https://old-domain.com` to `https://new-domain.com`.

If visitors right now type `http://old-domain.com` (normal http), then apache redirects to https.

What I would like is that both domains work at the same time.

**Question**

Is it possible to have two certificates at the same time, and ideally only use one IP for the Apache VirtualHost?

Or can a redirect be made, so I just install the `new-domain.com` SSL certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have two certificates at the same time, and ideally
>   only use one IP for the Apache VirtualHost?

Yes, using [Server Name Indication](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI). Your biggest hurdle with SNI will be the fact that it doesn't work with Internet Explorer on Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a redirect from the old to new domain or purchase another ip address and SSL Certificate for the new domain.

SNI is not support by quite a few clients http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#No_support

Comment: I second this recommendation - to get another IP address for the new domain. It should be a minor expense compared to the cost of purchasing a commercial SSL certificate.

Comment: This is the preferred way to do it since SNI does not work on many systems.  Just create a new IP based host with the old name and install its own cert. Put in your 301 redirect there.